# Why datatype isn't verified when validating XML with Schema?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, saxparser

Here is XML Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long" />
</xs:schema>
```

XML file that is validated for conformance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<id>invalid_data</id>
```

Java code that works with XML and should test conformance:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(false);
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
factory.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(xmlSchema)));
parser = factory.newSAXParser();
MySaxHandler handler = new MySaxHandler();
parser.parse(new File(xmlFile), handler);
```

During invocation of this code NumberFormatException is throwed in `characters` method of `MySaxHandler`. MySaxHandler also contains overriden methods warning, error and fatalError but they aren't executed.

I don't want this NumberFormatException being thrown. I want datatype being validated according to Schema. How do I do it?

Comment: should you be using validation class/method instead of parse method? Here is example: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/index.html

Comment: you have `factory.setValidating(false);` above.  is that a typo?  wouldn't you want `true` for validation?

Comment: @andrewcooke `factory.setValidating` is for DTD validation

Comment: ok, sorry.  this is probably wrong too, but have you tried setting the relevant sax feature?  they are listed at http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html#package_description and this (very old, using xerces 2) example suggests they might be needed http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/09/15/schema-validation.html (in particular, there is a validation feature whose default is unspecified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if it's simply a timing issue. The schema validator can't test the content of the element until the end element event is reached, but the text node is reported to the ContentHandler *before* the end element event is reached. Try masking the exception in your application to see if the validation error gets reported a bit later.

Comment: Yes, validation is actually performed if I mask exception. Thank you! But it seems strange to me to mask this exception inside `characters` method. Is it really what I should do?

Comment: Well, I don't think you should do anything in the characters() method other than copy the content to a buffer. Remember that the parser can break up the content into multiple calls on characters(), so you only know you have got all the content when the endElement() call comes.